# Genetic algorithm implementation for gas/power/water network operation optimizaiton

Tags: mathematics, simulation, power-transmission, electrical-grid, natural-gas

I have both practical and theoretical background in power, gas and water networks operation and I am familiar with the basics of genetic algorithm. I would like to dive into the network operation optimization topic. What literature would you recommend to learn the implementation of genetic algorithm to the network optimization problems? I have already prepared mathematical models for constrained optimization of the mentioned types of networks. So I am looking for the recommendations on the literature on coding/decoding techniques and selection, crossover and mutation scenarios from the network optimization perspective.

Most of the papers I found on this topic are focused on the results of the optimized operation of the networks and not on the genetic algorithm implementation process. Books and lecture notes covering this topic are offering general approach to the use and implementation of genetic algorithm, and I find it hard to apply techniques presented to the implementation of the genetic algorithms to my specific problem of network optimization.

Please help with recommendations of either papers or books or lecture notes covering implementation of genetic algorithm for network operation optimization problems.